# Keras model is of wrong class (R)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using `keras`(version 2.2.50) in R to build a simple sequential model. In order to work with a function of another package I need it to be of class `keras.models.Sequential`, however, it has the eight classes shown below:

```
library(keras)

model = keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 10, input_shape = 4, activation = "linear") %>%
  compile(optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.1), loss = "mae")

> class(model)
[1] "keras.engine.sequential.Sequential"                        
[2] "keras.engine.training.Model"                               
[3] "keras.engine.network.Network"                              
[4] "keras.engine.base_layer.Layer"                             
[5] "tensorflow.python.module.module.Module"                    
[6] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable"
[7] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base.Trackable"        
[8] "python.builtin.object"
```

What could be the reason for this and is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971763/problem-using-keras-sequential-model-for-reinforcelearn-package-in-r , you should ask the question only once.